# Could an AI be sentient?

Tags: philosophy, agi, sentience

In theory, could an AI become sentient, as in learning and becoming self-aware, all from its source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, if one could build a computing device that matched or exceeded the cognitive capabilities of a sentient being, it should be possible.

(Singlarity adherents believe we will one day be able to transfer the human mind into an artificial computing platform, and it logically follows that one could "hack" such a mind, or build from the ground up, to create a truly Artificial Intelligence.)

But this may be like fusion power, where the old adage is that it is "always 20 years away."

Answer (score 2):

***Yes***, an AI program can become sentient. Ray Kurzweil while giving a lecture at Singularity University on **The Accelerating Future** stated that human body is basically composed of approximately 23,000 little software programs called **GENES**. If you think about it, they are actually programs, composed of sequences of data. They are not written in C++ or Java, instead they use *3-D Protein Interaction*. They evolve with time and their evolution is the reason that species are able to survive even when their surroundings experience tragic changes. 
We are on the edge of a breakthrough where software will be able to do the same (evolving by themselves) efficiently. Today this is done one a basic level. Artificial Neural Network is a good example.

> It is predicted that we will be able to reverse engineer human brain by 2029. Prior to this we will be able to write codes that can stimulate human brain.

AI programs can be categorized into three:

1. Artificial Narrow Intelligence (ANI): This is a basic AI program that is good at good one thing. These programs are prominent nowadays. AI programs playing board games (like Chess, Reversi etc.) are example of these. They are good in only one thing.
2. Artificial General Intelligence (AGI): This is level 2 AI. This will be having a IQ level equivalent of humans. It will be able to do multiple tasks efficiently just like humans. This is where a program can have understanding of it's environment just like humans. Perception, rational behavior and others will be part of this program.
3. Artificial Super Intelligence (ASI): This is basically the ultimate level of AI. Average predicted date for a successful ASI is between 2045-2080. Ability of this program will be way more than that of combined intelligence of all humans on the planet. Things this program can do and think, will be beyond any (or all) human(s) to understand or comprehend.